# ASP.NET MVC 4 Routing is Matching, but Controller is Never Called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been struggling with a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project in VS 2010. I've got a very basic setup with a single controller (`SiteController`), a single route (`{action}`), and a single view (`Views/Site/Default.cshtml`). For some reason, I can't get it to display the view, even though the routes match according to RouteDebugger, and all I get is 404 errors. I thought it was Cassini being a jerk, so I installed IIS 7, but it's still not working. Here's the relevant code:

**SiteController**

```
/// Note: BaseController is in a different assembly I use to extend MVC and it works fine because I use it in a dozen other projects.
public class SiteController : BaseController {
    public ActionResult Default() {
        return base.View();
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig**

```
public class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(
        /// http(s)://{host}/{action}
        routes.MapRoute("6354af93-f979-44a4-ba9b-cc8ab775edf6", "{action}", new {
            action = "Default",
            controller = "Site"
        });

        /// http(s)://{host}/{*any}
        routes.MapRoute("04b41915-4455-4c11-96c2-38e6aedf929f", "{*any}", new {
            action = "Default",
            controller = "Site"
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the folder structure of the project:

```
App_Start
    BundlesConfig.cs
    FilterConfig.cs
    NinjectWebCommon.cs
    RouteConfig.cs
Controllers
    SiteController.cs
Models
Views
    Shared
        _Site.cshtml
    Site
        Default.cshtml
    Web.config
Global.asax
packages.config
Web.Config
```

Comment: Can you rename the Site folder to "Base" and see if it works?

Comment: Yup, still got 404 though.

Comment: @Alex, have you confirmed the Action Method executes?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - That isn't possible.  The View() method uses the route values, not the class name to determine which view to load.  Besides, you wouldn't get a 404 for not finding the view.  The 404 means it's not finding the action.

Comment: When you say things are in other assemblies, I am suspicious that your problem may be related to a namespacing issue.  Is your RouteConfig in the same namespace as your SiteController?  I also notice a Ninject configuration, are you using Ninject here and just not telling us?

Comment: @MystereMan, yes, I am using Ninject. I was thinking the same about the `BaseController` so I reverted `SiteController` to inherit from `Controller` again and it worked. Maybe its because the `BaseController` is compiled against MVC 3, although I've got MVC 4 projects using it without issues. Anyway, the action is now being called, which brings me back to the original issue I've been trying to get to work for the past 3 days which is "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" on the controller and Ninject not doing anything. Again, other project I have use the same setup fine...

Comment: @MystereMan I was curious to see if the routes were actually broken, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my `BaseController` class was causing the 404 errors. Not sure why, gonna have to check that project as well, but for now I've reverted the `SiteController` to inherit from `Controller` as is default.

**UPDATE**

I spent the last couple of hours rebuilding a .NET extensions solution I had which contained the `BaseController` I was referencing above. I re-targeted it use v4 assemblies and was able to plug it back in. So, I guess I was at fault for using an extension that was referencing v3 assemblies.

Comment: I run into this error when using an old library that referenced an old version of MVC and you are running the newest. You just need binding redirects to snap all versions of MVC to the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that I would recommend for debugging the issue if you are running out of ideas...

1. Setup a empty default MVC project on the machine using the vs2012 project template, run it and make sure everything is fine
2. Add in the base controller and use that in the DefaultController in the project template and make sure the default controller still works.
3. replace the default route with your customize route and make sure the default one still working
4. Add in the _site.cshtml to the default and make sure it still works.
5. Add in the sitecontroller and change the route to route to that

Comment: wouldnt this have made a better comment? I say this because, while all good ideas, this is NOT a solution.